# Xcode Storyboard Serious Issue Going Blank?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, storyboard, uistoryboard

I know there are a couple other questions on StackOverflow similar to this one, but they have different results and circumstances.  I have 1 Storyboard in my iPhone App (Tab Bar Application).  It has a total of about 7 different UIViewControllers.  Whenever I do anything (delete something, add an object) it goes blank, and all I have are gridlines. I have to completely click out of the storyboard file–onto a code file–and click to open the storyboard file again to make the contents show up. This is really frustrating and it is making me take twice as long on my work.

Unlike other questions, I only have one tab open and I am not doing anything else with the application, so closing other tabs does not fix my issue.  I tried everything, but there is no way that I am going to take the time to create a new Storyboard file and relink all of the connections.

If anyone else knows how to fix this, please assist me. It would be so greatly appreciated.  If anyone else has this issue please comment so that I can get an idea of how many have this issue (and that I am not the only one).

Comment: I occasionally get a blank storyboard but not under the circumstances you describe. You can restore it more quickly using the "crumb trail" at the top of the editor - select a specific scene or the main language version.

Comment: occasionally this happens to me.  i'm not certain what causes it, but the way i usually solve it is to click in items in the Document Outline, and they appear one by one.  the other solution has been to quit Xcode and re-start.

Comment: Does this happen in the new Xcode? Also, you might consider adding an answer with any solutions/workarounds you've found for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you may have to adjust the w h elements at the bottom of the Storyboard ... They got reset for me to wAny hAny when I switched to wCompact hAny it worked out.